# android:textFontWeight has no effect

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-typeface

When I use the `android:textFontWeight` attribute on a `TextView`, it doesn't select the appropriate font from the font family. I tested it on **API 28**, because the attribute is only available on 28+

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

The `myfont` font-family is defined like this:

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<font
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/myfont_regular" />
<font
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="200"
    app:font="@font/myfont_thin" />
```

On API 28, I expect the `TextView` to pick `myfont_thin`, but it doesn't. I also tried it with other weights with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `android:textFontWeight` support not all fonts.
It is works for example for:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
android:fontFamily="serif"
```

but ignored for other

```
android:fontFamily="monospace"
android:fontFamily="cursive"
```